# Python OOP Inheritance

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to implment inheritance into my school work but it is not working. This the code which I have written, this is a basic version of it:

```
from tkinter import *
class First(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(First,self).__init__(master)
        self._x = int(input("Int: "))

class Second(Frame):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Second,self).__init__(master)
        self._y = self._x + 9

class Third(First,Second):
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(Third,self).__init__(master)
        print(self._y)



root = Tk()
root.configure(background='light grey')
myGUI = First(root)
Third()
root.mainloop()
```

Im trying to make it make the user input a int then +9 then print it using inheritance. But i keep getting the error:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'
```

My code may look very messy but im new to python so apologies, thanks for help.

Comment: You never pass anything to `Third`: `Third()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the error says, `Third` requires one argument named `master`. You're not passing any arguments when you do `Third()`

You need to call it as `Third(root)`.